# JBOSS Wildfly 8, Hibernate ConstraintViolationException logging Off

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

`ConstraintViolationException` is being logged at level ERROR every time there is a constraint. The Hibernate logs this exception every time. The message is something like:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: 1 constraint violation(s) occurred during method validation.
Constructor or Method:
Argument values:
Constraint violations: 
 (1) Kind: PARAMETER
parameter index: 0
 message: 
root bean:
property path:
constraint:
```

and 100+ lines after this.

How to stop this logging for that error class?

Is it possible to turn it off inside wildfly's `logging.properties` or `standalone.xml` ?

Comment: Shouldn't you rather examine, and fix, the problem? The error is probably logged for a reason.

Comment: Yes. There is a constraint validation annotation. ConstraintViolationException is a runtime exception not an error. So there is no reason to log this exception in my opinion.